# Xamarin.Forms: How add Privacy Key in Visual Studio 2015 for IOS10

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, ios10

I want to use the **Media Plugin** for Xamarin.Forms in my project.
But for it to work on **IOS10** I need to add an security setting in the 'Info.plist' file from my IOS project.

As stated here: https://blog.xamarin.com/new-ios-10-privacy-permission-settings/

And also the steps are explained here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction-to-ios10/security-privacy-enhancements/#Setting-Privacy-Keys

But still I can't figure out how to do it.
In step 2 explain to do 'At the bottom of the screen, switch to the Source view.'. Problem is I can't find it.

Is there someone that knows the answer to my problem?
Thank you!

Comment: are you opening the info.plist file in your iOS project?

Comment: Yes, in Visual Studio 2015, then double clicking the file in directory 'Project.IOS'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that designer view is available in Visual Studio yet.

Open up the `info.plist` with a text editor and edit it manually. It's just XML so if you look at it for a second you'll figure out the structure.

Then just add this somewhere in the root `<dict>` tag somewhere.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to photos.</string>
```

If you *do* want to do it with the GUI you'll have to use Xamarin Studio or open it in Xcode directly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked!
I wasn't very sure if the only way was to add it via XML, so that's why I asked to be sure.